# VS2013 Fsharp project assembly reference bin debug not found

Tags: visual-studio-2013, f#, project-reference

In a solution with Fsharp projects (Visual Studio 2013), intellisense can start complaining that references to other Fsharp projects cannot be found. It then tries to locate the referenced dll file in the bin/Debug folder while in every project and solution wide in the configuration manager everything is configured to build a release. Also, when looking at the project reference properties the path is correct (i.e. the bin/Release folder) and the requested dll actually exists and is in the right folder. The problem disappears by just removing and adding the project reference again or by building the project (while it was build and working in the first place).

The problem can reoccur at any time, however, I cannot give a triggering event or problem case.

Is this a bug in VS2013?

Comment: Sounds like it could be a bug with the F# project system. If you can pin down specific steps to reproduce the problem, please file an issue at https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/issues

Comment: @latkin. I will be on the lookout to try to find a pattern.